# File sending stuck in the middle[Socket Programming]

Tags: java, c, sockets, network-programming, file-transfer

The following is a code snippet that I'm using to send a file to connection. The odd thing I'm facing is that the loop gets stuck in the middle for long files while the code works perfectly for small files. I transfered a file of 17636 bytes successfully however when I tried it for a file of size 1368622 bytes, the loop gets stuck at around 323850 bytes. Any idea?

```
f1.seekg(0,ios::beg);
            for(i=0;i<val;i++)
            {
                f1.get(ch);
                uch=(unsigned char)ch;
                nret=send(lsocket[index_control],(char*)&uch,sizeof(uch),0);
                if(nret<0)
                {
                    cout<<"\nlsocket["<<index_control<<"] : Network Connection Error.";
                    cout<<"\nlsocket["<<index_control<<"] : Socket Is Now UnBound.";
                    cout<<"\nlsocket["<<index_control<<"] : Abnormal termination of lsocket["<<index_control<<"]";
                    close(lsocket[index_control]);
                    pthread_exit(0);
                }
                cout<<"i="<<i<<"ch="<<ch;
            }
            cout<<"\nlsocket["<<index_control<<"] : File Sent Successfully";
```

**Edit** : The client at the other end is programmed in Java. The counterpart of send ie recv function cannot be used at client. This is why I'm forced to send 1 byte of file at a time.

Comment: You're sending one byte at a time? Why?

Comment: How do you send the entire file at once? I don't know of any such function in C++ that could transfer entire file at once.

Comment: (1) The opposite of sending a byte at a time is sending more than a byte at a time, not necessarily the entire file at once, but (2) there is `sendfile()`, since you ask.

Answer (score 2):

> File sending stuck

You are sending faster than the receiver is receiving. All the intermediate socket buffers have filled up, and TCP flow control is stalling the sender.

To solve this you would have to post the receiving code. However, I have no idea why you're sending one byte at a time. This is poor practice. Terrible. The normal way to send a file is as follows:

```
char buffer[8192]; // or more
int count;
while ((count = read(fileFD, buffer, sizeof buffer)) > 0)
{
    if (send(socketFD, buffer, count, 0) < 0)
    {
        perror("send");
        break;
    }
}
```

> Edit : The client at the other end is programmed in Java.

Irrelevant.

> The counterpart of send ie recv function cannot be used at client.

The Java counterpart of `recv()` is `InputStream.read()`, which can be used at the client, in any of its three overloads, and there is also `DataInputStream.readFully()`.

> This is why I'm forced to send 1 byte of file at a time.

*Non sequitur.* There is nothing here or anywhere else that forces you to send a byte at a time.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that the client running on the other end is programmed in Java. The counterpart of send ie recv function cannot be used at client.

Comment: @7_R3X That doesn't make the slightest difference to how you should send. Unclear why you would think otherwise.